# docx file to python in correct format

Tags: python-3.x, docx, finereader

I have a docx file created by FineReader (FineReader takes a pdf file and creates a text file with the text from the pdf). Now I want to read the file using python3. I used:

```
with open('file.docx') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

and this is was the outcome:

```
at \'ed og \'fd \'fattalast uj; at \'f3 \'fattalast sum ou og \'fa sum yv, ei sum aj, at g og k hava
```

this is what the text looks like in the docx file when I open it in a text editor:

```
at í og ý úttalast uj; at ó úttalast sum ou og ú sum yv, ei sum aj, at g og k hava
```

Any idea how to fix this encoding issue?

---

Btw. I also tried the follwing:

```
with open('file.docx', encoding='latin-1') as file:
    for line in file:
        l = line.encode("utf-8")
        print(l)
```

and this was the outcome:

```
at \\'ed og \\'fd \\'fattalast uj; at \\'f3 \\'fattalast sum ou og \\'fa sum yv, ei sum aj, at g og k hava
```

And I tried this:

```
import unicodedata
with open('file.docx') as file:
    for line in file:
        unicode = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', line)
        print(unicode)
```

and got:

```
at \'ed og \'fd \'fattalast uj; at \'f3 \'fattalast sum ou og \'fa sum yv, ei sum aj, at g og k hava
```

Comment: Docx is a binary format. You first need to export from word into a text format. I never used it for work but xlsx for example can be exported to CSV

Comment: You are right, dealing with the docx format first solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by opening the document with the following:

```
import unicodedata
import docx

doc = docx.Document("file.docx")
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    unicode = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', p.text)
    print(unicode)
```